# NSNumber in NSDictionary is always null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a project and want to add a NSNumber into a NSDictionary. But the it crashed because of the null value. So, I created another small program to check what happened. As you can see in the snapshot: Why the the value of NSNumber in NSDictionary is null?[image: The Snapshot of breakpoint]

Comment: I think its debugger problem try `NSLog` the `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I ran your code, and it worked fine. Does it always log NO?

Comment: BTW - Consider using modern Objective-C: `NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"number" : @YES };`

Comment: I don't see that.  In the screen image, the debugger has not yet executed like 16 where anum is assigned.

Comment: @danh Look at the variable output of `dict` in the debugger. It is showing a `null` value for the value.

Comment: BTW2 - Then do `BOOL b = [dict[@"number"] boolValue];`

Comment: That's odd - the pointer values are the same for the value in the dict and `num`... Perhaps garbage collection is misbehaving?

Comment: Thank you all. Maybe just a debugger problem, beacuse the result is right.

Comment: @SimonM iOS doesn't have GC.

Comment: Yeah - I never look at the collections that way.  (lldb) po is much more useful.  Take one more step in your debugger and you'll see anum correctly initialized.

Comment: Cause the crash problem in my project is not the reason, null value, but another small place, I confused. xD. Thanks!

Comment: @rmaddy Correct, I should have checked... :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run your code and I could reproduce the problem. But it seems like a debugger problem. For instance, if after your dictionary is created, go to the console and try printing the dictionary.

```
po dictionary
```

My result is like:

```
$4 = 0x2083e770 {
    number = 1;
}
```

So it's not null at all. Also, after that, anum is assigned correctly and b is set to YES. So it really looks like a debugger issue instead of a bug from you.

Comment: Thank you all. Very grateful to you for helping me.